# How can I play a video?

Tags: android

How can I play a video in Android? Where do I put my video file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could put the video in as a raw resource, and then access it using the MediaPlayer.

More on that here:

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/index.html

Comment: The link you provided will play video file from resource but its not videoView

Comment: VideoView vd = (VideoView)findViewById(R.id.Video);
         vd.setVideoPath("F:/SCHOGINI/work_apps/Video/res/raw/v.3GP");
         vd.start();

Answer (score 1):

Look at the 'APIDemos' project in the samples directory of the Android SDK. There is a MediaPlayerDemo.java and a VideoViewDemo.java files which should get you started.